# CKEditor contextmenu positions incorrectly in modal

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, ckeditor

Made a plugin that utilizes CKEditor contextmenu. When used inside a bootstrap modal, the first right-click results in an incorrect positioning of the menu. Subsequent attempts work fine.

Tough to debug:

CKEditor exists in one iframe and the contextmenu exists in its own separate iframe that gets generated at first use. That new iframe appears completely outside the modal, with a div wrapper, one level in from the outermost `<body>` tag on the page.

normal CKEditor iframe which exists inside the modal looks like this:

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" 
    class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" 
    title="Rich Text Editor, ControlLabel" tabindex="0" ...
```

contextmenu wrapper looks like this:

```
<div lang="en" id="cke_28" dir="ltr" class="cke cke_reset_all ...
    <iframe id="cke_28_frame" class="cke_panel_frame" ...
```

The contextmenu wrapper is getting inline position styles calculated against the `<body>` tag. It gets it wrong the first time you right-click to bring up the contextmenu.

```
z-index: 10001;
position: absolute;
top: 177px;                // wrong. too small.
left: 932.5px;
opacity: 1;
width: 130px;
height: 203px
```

[image: Contextmenu position problem]

Second time is correct. Click away, then right-click to bring the contextmenu back and you get a proper rendering:

```
z-index: 10001;
position: absolute;
top: 487px;       // correct. proper distance
left: 719.5px;
opacity: 1;
height: 203px;
width: 130px;
```

[image]

What gives? This has been a herculean debug effort since I've had to creep into iframes, one of which is dynamically generated (gotta use javascript tricks beyond what's offered by Chrome devtools).

There's an `open()` method in the contextmenu source code [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/plugin19.html#CKEDITOR-plugins-contextMenu-method-open), which starts like this:

```
open: function( offsetParent, corner, offsetX, offsetY ) {
                this.editor.focus();
                // ...
```

Having spent so much time already, before I start stepping through a mountain of code, I'm wondering if I'm even on the right track here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fix was an incredibly simple bootstrap css override.

```
body.modal-open {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Background scrolling was confusing the contextmenu coordinate calculations. It is my suspicion that by default a bootstrap modal will not prevent the background from being scrolled programmatically in all cases.

Bootstrap attaches the `.modal-open` class onto the `<body>` tag when there's an open modal.